# Arrays.binarySearch next index

Tags: java, algorithm

In java say, I have:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] arr = {1,1};
  int index = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, 1);
    System.out.println(index);
  }
}
```

This will **always** give the first index it finds, is there a way I can get the second one?

Comment: what makes you think it will always return the first index?  that's not what the [Arrays.binarySearch doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)) says.  in any case, binary search requires that the array must be sorted, so if there are multiple items with the same value, they will be at adjacent locations in the array.

Comment: Hmm, the official JavaDoc says:
'_If the array contains multiple elements with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be found._' The exact formulations may vary depending on the exact method used but the general idea stays the same. For reference see here [Java Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Comment: There is a way to get all of them -> [all occurences of an object in Arraylist, in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900585/trying-to-find-all-occurances-of-an-object-in-arraylist-in-java)